# ESP32 LCD 16/2 Русские буквы

Tags: arduino, поиск-библиотек, esp32

Есть ESP32, есть LCD дисплей 16/2, есть библиотека под работу этого дисплея на английском языке. Где найти библиотеку под русский язык, чтобы она работала на ESP32???

Comment: Да использовал библиотеку специально для esp32. Не, другая библиотека почему-то не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылка на библиотеку с github: [ESP8266_LCD_1602_RUS](https://github.com/ssilver2007/ESP8266_LCD_1602_RUS).
На esp32 работает 100%.
Для того чтобы нормально выводились int, тут нужно указывать ещё и `DEC`.
Т.е. `lcd.print(1, DEC);`. В противном случае постоянно будет выскакивать ошибка.

Comment: Потому что тут не любят когда просят предоставить что-то готовое и рабочее, ведь самостоятельно написать/модифицировать библиотеку это сложно(сарказм). Да и по более специфичным вопросам лучше на английский СО идти, но это нужно знать английский язык.

Answer (score 0):

ESP8266_LCD_1602_RUS недостаток в том что слишком мало русских букв можно использовать одновременно. Лучше покупать специальную версию дисплея с русским алфавитом на месте японского. Он не будет правильно работать с библиотекой ESP8266_LCD_1602_RUS, а для обычной библиотеки нужно будет написать транслятор в кодировку экрана.